# Wifi Direct Network

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Is it possible to create a wifi direct network on the existing android devices
and to do somethink like this:

- device A   is connected to  device B and device B   is connected to
- device C and to device A
- device A  sends a message to device C through device B

?

In other words, can a device be connected to more than one peer-groups 
and to be a router?
It is possible to programm somethink like this in Android?

Comment: u mean creating a wifi ?if u have crentials like ssid and ect then yes u can

Comment: Wi-Fi Direct, initially called Wi-Fi P2P, is a Wi-Fi standard that enables devices to connect easily with each other without requiring a wireless access point

Comment: Is it possible to do somethink like on this pic:
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140813/8is4jdlj.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Access Point using Wi-Fi Direct, so you can connect multiple devices.Furthermore, you don´t have to accept any Android-dialogs.